# Selecting Rows From a Table Based on A List

Tags: r, list, data-manipulation

I have this table:

```
col1 <- c("1","2", "3", "4", "5")
col1 <- sample(col1, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2))

col2 <- c("6","7", "8")
col2 <- sample(col2, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.4, 0.4))

col3 <- c("9","10", "11", "12")
col3 <- sample(col3, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4))

col4 <- rexp( 1000, 0.5)
col5 <- rexp( 1000, 0.5)
id <- 1:1000

table_1 = data.frame(id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
```

And this list:

```
f <- function(set) { 
    n <- length(set)
    masks <- 2^(1:n-1)
    lapply( 1:2^n-1, function(u) set[ bitwAnd(u, masks) != 0 ] )
}

sample_list = f(min(col1):max(col3))
```

I want to select rows from "table_1" based on entries in "sample_list". For example:

```
select = as.integer(runif(1, min = 1, max = 512))

>select
381

my_select = sample_list[select]

sample_list[381]
[[1]]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 9
```

Is there someway that I can "quickly" select all rows in "table_1" where (table_1$col1, table_1$col2, table_1$col3) have values that are contained in "my_select"?

This would be the equivalent of:

```
subset(table_1, col1 %in% c("3", "4", "5") &  col2 %in% c("6", "7") &  col3 %in% c("9"))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you mean all of the columns should have the value from the list index or just one column.

Here is one solution that returns the rows where all match

```
my_select <- function(index){
  where<- which(apply(table_1[2:4], 1, \(x) all(x  %in% sample_list[[index]])) |> t())
  where
}

[1] 131 146 174 179 205 272 396 450 500 512 574 589 619 669 673 703 736 751 887 893 925 992
```

Comment: @ Jahi: thank you so much! I wonder if there is a way to select rows from the original table with the same list of indexes? I will start working on it!

Comment: Not sure I follow. sorry I'm half asleep. Do you mean subsetting the table?

Comment: Can you please show me how to use this function you have defined? When I tried to use it, I got the following output: > my_select(286)
integer(0)  . Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah that means no match. It looks to see if all columns in (col1:col3) have a value present in the list index. I wasn't sure if that was your objective or not

Comment: @ Jahi: Thank you so much! Do you know why a second "where" is required in this function? Thank you!

Comment: The second where is equivalent to return(where).

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to understand the logic you used in this line: which(apply(table_1[2:4], 1, \(x) all(x  %in% sample_list[[index]])) |> t()) .... if you have time, can you please explain how you figured this out? thank you so much!

Comment: What does this mean? \(x) .... and why is a "Transpose" required t()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246124/discussion-between-jahi-zamy-and-antonoyaro8).