# Combing Two Selections Together

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Here is what I am starting with:

- Table_1:

This looks like this:

```
col1 <- c("1","2", "3", "4", "5")
col1 <- sample(col1, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2))

col2 <- c("6","7", "8")
col2 <- sample(col2, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.4, 0.4))

col3 <- c("9","10", "11", "12")
col3 <- sample(col3, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4))

col4 <- rexp( 1000, 0.5)
col5 <- rexp( 1000, 0.5)
id <- 1:1000

table_1 = data.frame(id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
```

- "sample_list"

This looks like this:

```
f <- function(set) { 
    n <- length(set)
    masks <- 2^(1:n-1)
    lapply( 1:2^n-1, function(u) set[ bitwAnd(u, masks) != 0 ] )
}

sample_list = f(min(col1):max(col3))
```

In another question, I learned how to write a function that selects rows from "Table_1" based on entries in "sample_list" :

```
# source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72840913/selecting-rows-from-a-table-based-on-a-list
my_select <- function(index){
  where<- which(apply(table_1[2:4], 1, \(x) all(x  %in% sample_list[[index]])) |> t())
  where
}
```

**Here is my question:**

I want to select some rows from table_1 based on sample_list:

```
selection_1 = table_1[my_select(as.integer(runif(1, min = 1, max = 512))),]
```

And some rows from table_1 based on some other random conditions:

```
a = rexp( 1000, 0.5)
b = rexp( 1000, 0.5)
c = rexp( 1000, 0.5)
d = rexp( 1000, 0.5)

selection_2 = subset(table_1, col4 > a & col4 < b & col5 > c & col5 < d )
```

Then, I only want to select the unique rows from both of these selections:

```
final_selection = rbind(selection_1, selection_2)

final_selection = final_selection[!duplicated(final_selection), ]
```

- Is there a more direct/easier way to do this?

Thank you!